# Exporting from Illustrator causes a weird path effect

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, svg, save

When I use the image trace feature in Illustrator I'm able to create a pretty high quality vector of an image. However, when I export it as an `.svg` file the paths aren't "just right" and it causes you to see white space in between. Like This monkeys nose:

[image]

Does anyone know of a way to fix this, or at least a workaround to make it less noticeable?

Answer (score 1):

There are merely **on screen** anti-aliasing areas.

Save the art for the web using the `Art Optimized` anti-alias setting and they won't show.

Print the art and they won't show.

These only happen *on screen*.

An easy fix is to just put a filled rectangle or something behind the artwork. If you place a black shape behind that image, all those on screen hairlines will vanish (on screen).

Answer (score 0):

*Make sure that every path gets a thin stroke in the same color as the fill*.

I wouldn't know how to do this automatically in Inkscape or AI, but depending on your how geek you are, you can do search and replace in a text editor on the SVG file.

SVG files are human readable ASCII files (well, kinda readable). You'd need to use a text-editor that can do Regular Expression (regexp) search, like Sublime or TextWrangler on Mac (and maybe Notepad++ on PC?). In the regexp, you'd need to include a reference, something like

```
search for: [  fill:"(.*)" ]
replace:  [ fill:"\1" stroke:"\1" ]
```

This is an example, it won't work literally.

That being said, there might me scripts or plugins or core functionality out there, that will give every path a stroke matching to its' fill.